# Mocha can't find the ID inside a input field - react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, mocha.js

I'm trying to get the text of an input through the .text(); method from Selenium. But everytime I try to fetch the element, it outputs that the ID in question was not found.

(i'm using the Input from nativebase, but I already tried to test it with textinput native component)

```
                      <Form>
                            <Item
                                testID='input_nomePaciente_formPacientes'
                                stackedLabel>
                                <Label style={styles.label}>Nome</Label>
                                <Input value={this.state.paciente.nome.toUpperCase()}
                                    style={styles.inputForm}
                                    testID='input_testID'
                                    autoCorrect={false}
                                    keyboardType={(Platform.OS === 'android') ? 'visible-password' : ''}
                                    autoCapitalize='none'
                                    onChangeText={(text) => this._updateItem('nome', text, 0)} />
                            </Item>
```

I can interact with the element with sendKeys(); and click(); through the Item testID, but I can't interact with anything inside the input. I also can't get the value of the field through the Item testID.

Here's how I'm trying to get the output:

```
let testID = await driver.elementByAccessibilityId("input_testID");
            let testIDValue = await testID.text();

            console.warn(testIDValue);
```

Comment: Apparently, the input isn't even visible to selenium-webdriver. If I try to store the input into a variable and console.warn() it, it just outputs with the value "false". But the text input is visible. So very very visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that mocha/selenium won't find imported nativebase components. Tried to get the input through  native component, and it worked out just fine.

This works perfectly:

```
<Label style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>Login</Label>
      <TextInput // react-native input component
          autoCapitalize='none'
          testID='input_login'
          editable={true}
          autoCorrect={false}
          keyboardType={(Platform.OS === 'android') ? 'visible-password' : ''}
          onChangeText={(item) => this.setState({ login: item })}
          value={this.state.login} 
       />
```

This won't work even if you cross your fingers:

```
<Form>
      <Item
           testID='input_nomePaciente_formPacientes'
           stackedLabel>
           <Label style={styles.label}>Nome</Label>
           <Input // nativebase input component
              value={this.state.paciente.nome.toUpperCase()}
              style={styles.inputForm}
              testID='input_testID'
              autoCorrect={false}
              keyboardType={(Platform.OS === 'android') ? 'visible-password' : ''}
              autoCapitalize='none'
              onChangeText={(text) => this._updateItem('nome', text, 0)} />
      </Item>
</Form>
```